# Extend lifetime of a variable for thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, lifetime

I am reading a string from a file, splitting it by lines into a vector and then I want to do something with the extracted lines in separate threads. Like this:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::thread;
fn main() {
    match File::open("data") {
        Ok(mut result) => {
            let mut s = String::new();
            result.read_to_string(&mut s);
            let k : Vec<_> = s.split("\n").collect();
            for line in k {
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    println!("nL: {:?}", line);
                });
            }

        }
        Err(err) => {
            println!("Error {:?}",err);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this throws an error, because `s` will go out of scope before the threads are started:

```
s` does not live long enough
main.rs:9           let k : Vec<_> = s.split("\n").collect();
                                     ^
```

What can I do now? I've tried many things like `Box` or `Arc`, but I couldn't get it working. I somehow need to create a copy of `s` which also lives in the threads. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, fundamentally, is that `line` is a borrowed slice into `s`.  There's really nothing you can do here, since there's no way to guarantee that each `line` will not outlive `s` itself.

Also, just to be clear: there is *absolutely no way* in Rust to "extend the lifetime of a variable".  It simply cannot be done.

The simplest way around this is to go from `line` being *borrowed* to *owned*.  Like so:

```
use std::thread;
fn main() {
    let mut s: String = "One\nTwo\nThree\n".into();
    let k : Vec<String> = s.split("\n").map(|s| s.into()).collect();
    for line in k {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("nL: {:?}", line);
        });
    }
}
```

The `.map(|s| s.into())` converts from `&str` to `String`.  Since a `String` owns its contents, it can be safely moved into each thread's closure, and will live independently of the thread that created it.

**Note**: you *could* do this in nightly Rust using the new scoped thread API, but that is still unstable.